# laravel - Call to a member function map() on array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make an array on my contact list, basing on my message table `fromContact` relation:

```
    $messages = Message::where('offer_id', $id)->get();
    $contacts = array();
    foreach($messages as $message){
      $contacts[] = $message->fromContact;
    }
```

next I'm trying to make a map on contact, using $unreadIds that are result of other query on messages table:

```
    $contacts = $contacts->map(function($contact) use ($unreadIds) {
        $contactUnread = $unreadIds->where('sender_id', $contact->id)->first();
        $contact->unread = $contactUnread ? $contactUnread->messages_count : 0;
        return $contact;
    });
```

and this is not working... I've got simply message with error: 
`Call to a member function map() on array`

and I understand it, I should not use map() on array - so I tried many ways to convert it to object - all failed.

for example 
converting contacts into object after array loop

```
 $contacts = (object)$contacts;
```

gives error: `"message": "Call to undefined method stdClass::map()",`

Maybe anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use laravel helper collect on the array then use map.

```
$collection = collect($contacts);

$collection->map(function($contact) use ($unreadIds) {
    $contactUnread = $unreadIds->where('sender_id', $contact->id)->first();
    $contact->unread = $contactUnread ? $contactUnread->messages_count : 0;
    return $contact;
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: I declared empty `$contacts = collect([]);` before foreach loop, but this also works!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!